# Calling Array.prototype.map with Math.max returns array of NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does `[1, 2, 3].map((x) => Math.max(x))` return `[1, 2, 3]`

yet `[1, 2, 3].map(Math.max)` returns `[NaN, NaN, NaN]` ?

I would have thought since `[1, 2, 3].map(Number)` returns `[1, 2, 3]`, the same would true for using `Math.max` in the same way.

Especially since `Math.max(3) == Number(3)`.

Comment: it's because of the array as callback parameter. `Math.max` expects numbers, not a string with numbers, separated with dots. this would lead to `NaN`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Tricky_use_case

Comment: edit: dots are commas ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax) invokes the callback with three arguments:

1. The current array element.
2. The index of the current element.
3. The array `map` was called on.

So `[1, 2, 3].map(Math.max)` is not equivalent to `[1, 2, 3].map((x) => Math.max(x))`, but to `[1, 2, 3].map((x, i, arr) => Math.max(x, i, arr))`.

And `Math.max(1, 0, [1, 2, 3])` is `NaN` because the `[1, 2, 3]` array becomes `"1,2,3"` when stringified, which becomes `NaN` when converted to a number.

Comment: This broke my heart.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):`Math.max(...[1,2,3])`

Comment: You can, but 1) that doesn't return `[1,2,3]` either and 2) has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: It relates to Math.max, he needs to know!